# Run through a td element and get all href from anchors to put in a Array

Tags: jquery

I need to run through this td element and get all **href** from anchors.

```
var title_href = [];

    $('td.cont-mod-none-options a').each(function(){
        title_href.push(jQuery(this).first().contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).text());

        console.log(title_href);

    });
```

This js above is what I am using but unfortunately is not working.

The code above is my HTML

> ```
> <td class="cont-mod-none-options" valign="top" align="right">
>   <img src="/images/clear.gif" height="5">
>   <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[&nbsp;
>   <a href="/anchor1" class="cont-mod-none-options">copy</a>
>   &nbsp;|&nbsp;
>   <a href="/anchor2" class="cont-mod-none-options">cut</a>
>   &nbsp;]&nbsp;
>   <img src="/images/clear.gif" width="2">
>   <a href="/anchor3" class="cont-mod-none-options">
>       <img src="/images/edit.gif" width="28" height="12" border="0">
>   </a>
>   <img src="/images/clear.gif" width="2">
>   <img src="/images/editupOFF.gif" width="12" height="12" border="0">
>   <img src="/images/clear.gif" width="2">
>   <a href="/anchor4" class="cont-mod-none-options">
>       <img src="/images/editdown.gif" width="12" height="12" border="0">
>   </a>
>   <img src="/images/clear.gif" width="2">
>   <a href="/anchor5" class="cont-mod-none-options">
>       <img src="/images/editX.gif" width="12" height="12" border="0">
>    </a>
>   <br>
>   <img src="/images/clear.gif" height="2"><
> /td>
> ```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand, you want to HREF but get the text?

Comment: I need the HREF in the anchors Karl

Comment: So you want `title_href.push(this.href)`?

Comment: I wanna add the href from all anchors in this array

Comment: I think i've understand that, but the snippet above doesn't do that? Check the console : http://jsfiddle.net/9Vwn4/

Comment: I see know.
Thank you
I am going to try

Comment: Karl, the code is getting 5 arrays with the same content.
How can I get just 1 array?

Comment: You are logging the array 5 times, but you only have 1 array. Get the console log out of the loop and it will show it only once.

Comment: Thank you again.

Karl, How I could use these array to create new anchors with the href respectively?

Comment: By looping inside the array, you can create an anchor on every iterations.

Comment: Karl, How can I loop inside the array in this case?

Comment: `$.each(title_href, function(index, value){})`

Comment: Karl, do you have an example?
Thank you for all help

Comment: Example : http://jsfiddle.net/9Vwn4/1/

Answer (score 0):

You code is quite close, but just a bit more complicated than you need for this task.

Also it's unclear whether want the whole URL from each `href` or just the path that is explicitly in the code.

Here is code that will push both options to arrays and display the result in the console.

```
var hrefs = [];
var paths = [];

$('td.cont-mod-none-options a').each(function(){
    hrefs.push(this.href);  
    paths.push(this.href.split('/').pop())
});

console.log('The full URLs are:' , hrefs);
console.log('And the specific paths are:' , paths);
```

If you want the full URLs, you can use the `hrefs` array. If you just want the paths that appear in your HTML code, you can use the `paths` array.